# "only unbounded wildcards allowed in array creation expression" for Generic type of array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hashmap

I have a compile error of "only unbounded wildcards allowed in array creation expression" when I use

```
    Map<Integer,Object>[] returnArray= new Map<Integer,Object>[2];
```

While if I remove the generic type like :

```
    Map<Integer,Object>[] returnArray= new Map[2];
```

It will be fine but I will have a waring for this.

**Why is that? What's the problem of having generic type for an array?**

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1692544&seqNum=2

Answer (score 0):

java doesnt allows you to create the same.
Please use the following

`Map<String, Object>[] returnArray= (Map<String, Object>[]) new Map[10];`

Comment: would you please explain what's the problem with <T,F>for creating an array